# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Register`.

this is my register codes :

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '../../../components/atoms/Button'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUserAPI } from '../../../config/redux/action';

class Register extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',  
  }

  handleChangeText = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleRegisterSubmit = async () => {
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    const res = await this.props.registerAPI({email, password}).catch(err => err);
    if (res) {
      this.setState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }) 
    }  
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="auth-container"> 
      <div className="auth-card">
        <p className="auth-title">Register Page</p>
        <input className="input" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeText} value={this.state.email} />
        <input className="input" id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" onChange={this.handleChangeText} value={this.state.password} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleRegisterSubmit} title="Register" loading={this.props.isLoading} />
      </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const reduxState = (state) => ({
  isLoading: state.isLoading
})

const reduxDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
  registerAPI: (data) => dispatch(registerUserAPI(data));
})

export default connect(reduxState, reduxDispatch)(Register);
```

App

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TopupPage from '../TopupPage';
import Register from '../Register';
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard/Layout';
import Login from '../Login';
import Homepage from '../Homepage';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../../../config/redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

function App(){
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Homepage} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/TopupPage" component={TopupPage} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </div>
      </Router>
   </Provider>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
  <Route path="/login" component={<Login/>} />
```

to

```
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Also here is a syntax error:

```
const reduxDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
  registerAPI: (data) => dispatch(registerUserAPI(data));
})
```

you should remove ';'.

Comment: can you remove register route temporary and check if error exists, then add it again to ensure error is related to register.

Comment: I've checked your register code and seems does not have any problem. I'm sure problem  was related to login route.

Comment: yes the problem is the register and login page both have the same problem

Comment: can you remove ';' and check again?

Comment: can you provide a codesanbox link to check your code?

Answer (score 0):

As error says, you are passing some object in place where primitive value should be.

My best gess is that in `reduxState` you should have something like this:

```
const reduxState = (state) => ({
        isLoading: state.someKeyWhichYouAreMissing.isLoading
    })
```

Best way to debbug is to replace your entire render with:

```
render() {
  console.log(this.state.email, this.state.password, this.props.isLoading)
  return null;
}
```